# Cloudera CDH4 installation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera-cdh

I see the below step in CDH4 MRV1 installation instructions at:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Quick-Start/cdh4qs_topic_3_2.html

**Step 4: Create the MapReduce system directories:**
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir -p /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/staging
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 1777 /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/staging
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown -R mapred /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred

But I am not able to figure out where this directories are used. Are these well known locations or these directory paths are configured in some config files. If so can I use any structure I want?

Answer (score 1):

These directories will be used by MapReduce. They match the value specified in the default configuration. I would not change them unless you have a good reason. But in the end, sure, you can configure a different location once you're up and running.